# What's wrong with this mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/errors/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1/ [L]
```

The first and last line work, they ensure that all content from that domain goto that subdirectory. The two in the middle I am attempting to keep from redirecting. I need to access those 2 folders from the subdirectory, but the HTTP_HOST just sends it back to the same folder (error 404).

I want it to ignore that rule if it's looking for `domain.com/content/(.*)` or `domain.com/content/(.*)`. Please note that I do not have access to server config, and .htaccess is the only way I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest compacting your .htaccess code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*(domain|errors|content)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . /domain%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]
```

- `.` needs to be escaped as `\.`
- `[NC]` is for ignore case comparison
- Negative URI match for `errors` and `content` can be combined in single rule with OR `|`
- %{REQUEST_URI} already has your original URI so no need to capture that
- Added `domain` in negative match to avoid infinite looping

Comment: You sir are a God. Solved my one week problem in less than 5 minutes. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I hit a roadblock. I want to use SymLinks from within the `/domain/` folder. So let's say... `http://domain.com/forum/1-general/` which is really `http://domain.com/index.php?area=forum&id=1`. I'm currently using this mod_rewrite in a .htaccess in the `/domain/` folder: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9*])-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/ index.php?module=$1&id=$2 [L]`. It works, but the negative match in the root .htaccess is having no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*domain/(errors|content)/ [NC]` for your .htaccess inside `/domain/`. If you still have issues pls provide your root and `/domain/` .htaccess content and I will try to assist you with that.

Comment: It did not work. Here is the .htaccess code for `/`: http://gyazo.com/e37fe1a563a4f510f30a9fac53471d1d.png and here is the .htaccess code for `/domain/`: http://gyazo.com/b9d11b5c4328da16c65f39be08784621.png

Comment: Thanks for making it available. May I also for which URIs it is not behaving? Is this the URI `http://domain.com/errors/`

Comment: May I know which URIs are NOT working for you? I tried on my local install and seems to be working fine.

Comment: eg: `/forum/1-general` gets redirected properly but this one is not `/content/1-general` since we have a negative match for `/content/`

Comment: Yea. When I symlink in `/forum/1-general/`, I guess it thinks its really in `/content/1-general/`. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: If I am understanding you, when I look in `/content/` through the symlink `/.../#-.../`, it thinks its in `/content/#-.../`.

Comment: With above 2 .htaccess you supplied. When I opened this URL in my browser: `http://localhost/forum/1-general/` it got **internally** redirected to `http://localhost/admin/index.php?module=forum&id=1` I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: But when I opened this link: `http://localhost/forum/1-general/` in browser, it gave me 404 since .htaccess rules **excluded** this URL.

Comment: The 2nd last reply you made is what I want. Except when I try to access `/content/` from `/forum/1-general/`, it doesn't exist for some reason.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my last comment, here is how it is behaving for me: `http://localhost/content/1-general/` gave me `404` but `http://localhost/forum/1-general/` got redirected to `http://localhost/admin/index.php?module=forum&id=1`. Is it behaving differently for you?

Comment: When I view `/forum/1-general/`, the internal redirect is to `/index.php?module=forum&id=1`. Which is correct. However, if I'm using SymLinks in the `/domain/` folder (as from original post), when I try to access files in the content folder, such as `/content/background.png`, it does not work.

Comment: Ah ok, probably now I understand your problem better. But you already have `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the top that should take care of it. I will get hold of a Linux based installation to recreate the setup like you and test it there.

Comment: I have one doubt. If you using image like this: `<img src="/content/background.png">` and you have content folder under root then why do you even need to create a symbolic link? Because image will show up even without that. Also when something is not working can you show me relevant apache's error.log messages for that. That is usually very helpful info.

Comment: That was my problem, I forgot the document root `/` in front of the relative path (I was only using `content/background.png`. Now it works, thanks a bunch man!

Answer (score 2):

The regular expressions in your conditions are only matching requests for `/errors/` *exactly*, because you have included the start-of-string and end-of-string anchors (`^` and `$`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/errors/$
```

Since you want your condition to match for all requests *starting* with `/errors/`, you should get rid of the `$` at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/errors/
```

The same obviously applies for the `/content/` condition.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but it's not having the effect I want.